# How to fix error: could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 runtime environment in '(null)'

Tags: java, installation

I have researched this and none of the solutions that I have seen have fixed my error.

What is happening is I tried to install Java EE version got the above error and then found out that I must install Java SE first.  So I installed Java SE and set the JAVA_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0 which is where I installed my JDK.  I also put C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin in my PATH variable.  Still not working.  I also tried the JAVA_HOME variable with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin and that didn't work.  I also tried installing without the PATH variable being updated to where I put my JDK.

I'm really getting confused as to why this is happening. I've had Java before and I don't recall having this much trouble installing it.

PS I don't install from the command line I just click the download icon in Firefox and then click the download.

Comment: what happens when you do java -version or javac -version in your cmd line?

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Java SE and Java EE?

Comment: and what IDE are you using?

Comment: C:\Users\mitch>java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

C:\Users\mitch>javac -version
javac 1.8.0

Comment: Also, I'm running 64-bit version of Java.
At the time of this error I had no ide but I just installed Eclipse today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall everything, all of it.

Then go to your Program Files folder (and (x86) folder if on a 64bit Windows) and physically remove any Java folders.

Reinstall Java SE and then the EE packages.  Sometimes Windows appears to get a bit confused and you need to help it figure out what to do.

Answer (score 45):

Try running the installer at your commandline and pass the path of the JRE instead of the JDK.

For Example:

```
java_ee_sdk7-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8"
```

Comment: Even this simple stuff helped me too. I tried a lot over the net but this simple above line did the magic. BTW, I've 7 64bit OS but used "java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows" to get going without issues...---THANKS Moboid

Comment: This is the line in my case : java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25"

Comment: I found that pointing at the 64-bit JRE (e.g. c:\program files\Java\jre6" did *not* work but pointing at the 64-bit JDK in the same directory root (c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_45) did.

Comment: works with java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-windows-x64-ml -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112"

Comment: This is the best answer. Pointing to the right jre in the system does the trick, thanks a lot. Will pass it on to my IT department.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem and even downloading the version without JDK didn't help!
I simply installed it from the terminal with passing the JRE For Example:

`java_ee_sdk7-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"`

and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but an additional step was required in order to install using the command line. In the command window (on my Windows 10 laptop) I had to use:

```
cmd /d
```

to tell the cmd window to ignore registry AutoRun commands before the java installation executable would run. After using cmd /d, and changing to the directory where the .exe file was at, the following worked:

```
java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows-x64.exe -j "%JAVA_HOME%"
```

Where JAVA_HOME is a system environment variable pointing to an existing JDK installation (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall, go to the glassfish folder and open the command prompt, then type:

```
uninstall.exe -j <The path to your JRE>
```

Answer (score 0):

These points may be helpful.

1. `java EE SDK7` contains `glassfish v4.0` and it compatible with `JDK6` and `JDK7`.
2. `java EE SDK8` contains `glassfish v5.0`, it compatible with only `JDK7 and JDK8`, not `JDK` 9 or beyond.
3. So environment variable `JAVA_HOME` has to point to the root directory of one of the mentioned `JDK`. and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` should be added to environment variable path
4. Despite having followed all of the above, setup of `java EE SDK7` gets error:

> could not find the required version of the Java(TM;

as Bakudan and laf8 said,
open cmd using run, with /d /a options as followed.

```
cmd /d /a
```

and next run SDK7-setup  with -j option like this command

```
sdk7.exe -j "%JAVA_HOME%"
```

note that `%JAVA_HOME%` enclosed BY ""

Answer (score -1):

This was happening to me when I tried to run the Java EE installer. What I did, was to download from Oracle a Java EE version which didn't include the JDK, because it was already installed in my system. Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

1. Open regedit.
2. goto :HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\
3. set CurrentVersion to desired JDK version.
4. Check JavaHome and RuntimeLib path's for selected jdk version folder

Check JavaHome and RuntimeLib path's for selected jdk version folder 
example: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7".

example:

- JavaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
- RuntimeLib=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Source: http://tech-read.com/2009/05/19/how-to-solve-error-could-not-find-java-runtime-2-environment-while-opening-an-ide/